# How can I get the shovel in Monkey Island 2

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge

When starting the game, I found myself in town standing in front of a panel with a shovel attached.

I tried to take the shovel but the game tries to get the panel and tells me it is impossible.

Is there a way to take the shovel?

Having already played Monkey Island 2 (a long time ago), I remember that the shovel might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pick up the shovel, the sign is surely too heavy. Pick up the sign instead.  It will get you the shovel. :)

You can do that either before or after encountering Largo. He won't take the shovel away from you.

Comment: +1 for the edit. I do believe you have to encounter Largo before you can pick up anything useful. IIRC, after encountering Largo, you can pick up the shovel directly.

Comment: Yes, encountering Largo did it. Looks like having already played the game is not that much of an advantage :-)